# jQuery sortable performance issue on heavy items

Tags: jquery, performance, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a performance issue on trying to sort an element with a grid containing only 1000 rows. There is a latency on the dragging part that i want to solve.

Code part:

```
$("#layoutSouthContainer")
        .sortable({
            refreshPositions: true,
            connectWith:"#layoutSouthContainer",
            handle: "> .module-header",
            axis: 'x'
        }).droppable({
            accept: ".dockable",
            tolerance: "pointer",
            containment: "#layoutSouthContainer"
        });
```

Demo => http://jsfiddle.net/27LMp/2/

Am i doing something wrong?
Is there a better way to do this?
Is it only possible having this part being fluid?

Comment: To be honest I think redrawing that entire container and its contents on every mouse move event is a bit too much. How about dragging a helper instead? http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-helper
I don't see anything that's wrong in the sense that it's causing the stuttering, just that the dragged container is quite large DOM-wise.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I tried this workaround with a custom helper but the result is not enought fluid to be a solution.

Comment: Because the main problem comes from the heavy structure of the table, i changed the plugin and there is no more problem. So, for those who will encounter this situation, before coding, think about the weight of your plugins ;)

Comment: Which plugin have you used? @Arngrim